# Remains the selected text in a TextBox still selected or focused after clicking a button

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have 2 buttons in my winform project. I want to add `<b></b>` or `<i></i>` around the selected text in a TextBox if user click button. I want the selected text still remains focused after clicking each button. With the following code after clicking a button the focused selected text disappears. How may I solve this?

```
private void btnBold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string selectedTxt = TextBox1.SelectedText;
       TextBox1.SelectedText = "<b>" + selectedTxt + "</b>";
   }

private void btnItalic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        string selectedTxt = TextBox1.SelectedText;
        TextBox1.SelectedText = "<i>" + selectedTxt + "</i>";
   }
```

Comment: You can build a Custom Control, derived from Button, then just set `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);` in its Constructor, so it doesn't steal the focus when clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the slectedtext index via `SelectionStart` property. Then set `SelectionLength` and call method `ScrollToCaret` to "focused selected text".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int selectlength = textBox1.SelectedText.Length;
    textBox1.SelectedText = "<b>" + textBox1.SelectedText + "</b>";
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.SelectionStart = index; // set the start position
    textBox1.SelectionLength = selectlength  + 7; // set length
    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: Is textBox1.ScrollToCaret(); necessary?  when I remove it, still works.

Comment: @Javad-M Yes, you can remove it. It is used to scroll the contents of the textbox to the current caret position. You can refer to this [TextBoxBase.ScrollToCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @Javad-M If this answer helps you. Please click `√` to mark it as answer.